Talend : How to use tReplaceList to find and replace CR LF (newline) in string
I have some data coming from an Oracle database that contains "CR LF". I use a tDBInput component to read that data and feed it into a Redshift table.
In the middle I have a tReplaceList that is feeded by a parameter table contain a list of forbidden character, "|" being one of them.
The problem being the CRLF is breaking my tDBOutputBulkExec.
I want to add CRLF to the list. I've tried everything like "\r" "\n" "\r\n", char10 char13 etc.... But nothing has been working.
After an inspection of the code of the tReplaceList component I saw that it use the Pattern.quote() method on my parameter input before using the replaceAll.
searchPatterntReplaceList_2 = java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(searchtReplaceList_2);
Which mean it doesn't interpret the CR LF I am trying to feed it.
How can I replace this character ?

With a tReplace component in advanced mode, you can use the expression
"(\r\n|\r|\n|\n\r)"

and replace a match with an ""
With a tReplaceList, I don't know if it's possible to do something like that.
